# Numpy: Efficient mapping of single values in np arrays

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, vectorization

I have a 3D numpy array respresenting an image in HSV color space (shape = (h=1000, w=3000, 3)).

The last dimension of the image is [H,S, V]. I want to subtract 20 from the H channel from all the pixels IF the pixel value is >20 , but leave S and V intact.
    I wrote the following vectorized function:

```
def sub20(x):
# x is a array in the format [H,S, V]
       return np.uint8([H-20, S, V])
 vec= np.vectorize(sub20, otypes=[np.uint8],signature="(i)->(i)")
 img2= vec(img1)
```

What this vectorised function does is to accept the last dimension of the image [H,S,V] and output 
[H-20, S, V]
 I dont know how to make it subtract 20 if H is greater than 20.  it also takes 1 minute to execute. I want the script to accept live webcam feed. Is there any way to make it faster?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `np.vectorize`.  Since you read the docs well enough to use `otypes` you've also read its performance disclaimer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply slice with condition:

```
img1[:,:,0][img1[:,:,0]>=20] -= 20
```

Or also make use of np.where:

```
img1[:,:,0] = np.where(img1[:,:,0]>=20, img1[:,:,0]-20, img1[:,:,0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use the vectorize function?

Otherwise you could only use the following command:

```
# if you want to make change directly on same image.
img1[:,:,0] -= 20

# if you want to leave img1 in the same state.
img2 = np.array(img1)
img2[:,:,0] = img1[:,:,0] - 20
```

**Update (12:08 - 5.4.2020)** 
To incorporate that values never get below 0 I would recommend to compute it in two steps as Mercury mentioned:

```
# if you want to make changes directly on same image.
img1[:,:,0] -= 20
img1[img1[:,:,0] < 0] = 0

# if you want to leave img1 in the same state.
img2 = np.array(img1)
img2[:,:,0] = img2[:,:,0] - 20
img2[img2[:,:,0] < 0] = 0
```

Comment: oh I see. Thank you. I tried it, it works =),  but now i face another problem: if the value is less than 20 then it becomes negative, and images cant have negative H values. How can I efficiently subtract 20 only if H >=20?